# Solving Pascal's Triangle (nCk) in Assembly Recursion

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

i am currently stuck with getting the answer from a combination problem. My basecase works just fine. I think the problem is at evaluating combination(n-1,k) and then evaluating combination(n-1,k-1).

Here's my code: n and k are inputs from user.

```
sub esp, 2
push word[n]
push word[k]
call combi
pop word[ans] ;store yung combi value sa ans

;convert to ascii string value
add word[ans], 30h

;print answer
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, ans
mov edx, 2
int 80h

jmp exit


combi:
    mov ebp, esp

    mov ax, word[ebp+4] ;ax = k
    cmp [ebp+6], ax     ;if (n==k)
    je basecase

    cmp word[ebp+4],0   ;cmp k = 0
    je basecase

    ;combi(n-1,k)
    mov ax, [ebp+6] ; ax = n
    mov bx, [ebp+4] ; bx = k

    dec ax ;n-1

    ;execute again
    sub esp, 2
    push ax
    push bx
    call combi
    pop cx      ;stores to cx popped value combi(n-1,k)
    mov ebp, esp ;update pointers

    ;combi(n-1,k-1)
    push ax
    dec bx
    push bx
    call combi
    pop dx     ;stores to dx popped value combi(n-1,k-1)
    mov ebp, esp ;update pointers

    add cx, dx ;combi(n-1,k) + combi(n-1,k-1)

    mov word[ebp+8], cx 
    jmp combi_exit


basecase:
    mov word[ebp+8], 1

combi_exit:
    ret 4
```

Hoping for your kind responses and brilliant ideas! Thank you!

Comment: [edit] to add more details on the cases where it's wrong, to make this a [mcve].  Use a debugger to single-step your code and watch registers, so you can see where it stops working the way you expect.

Comment: This `add word[ans], 30h` is obviously wrong, though.  It only works for a single-digit number.  (See the multi-digit number FAQ entry in [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).)  And why are you using 16-bit operations everywhere in a 32-bit Linux process?  It's significantly more efficient to use 32-bit operations.

Comment: does not compile, missing some parts (like data definition).

Answer (score 0):

To fix your recursion, the middle part of `combi:` has a problem:

```
    ...
    call combi
    pop cx      ;stores to cx popped value combi(n-1,k)
;* ^ this freed the allocated space for result
    mov ebp, esp ;update pointers
;* not needed, as you will not use EBP right now, and next call destroys it

    ;combi(n-1,k-1)
    push ax
;* ^ pushing first argument, but no stack space reserved for result
    dec bx
    push bx
    call combi
    ...
```

To <strike>fix</strike> you can adjust that part to:

EDIT: this will not work correctly for 2+ deep recursion, as you don't preserve registers as needed, the whole recursion architecture requires more care and I would opt simply to rewrite it with simpler design in the first place, than fixing all these minor problems. This "fix" will at least stop the segfaulting.

```
    ...
    call combi
    mov cx,[esp]      ;stores to cx value combi(n-1,k)
;* ^ keeps the stack space reserved (not popping)
    ;combi(n-1,k-1)
    push ax
    ...
```

There's of course the other problem with your output being correct only for single digit numbers, but just search stack overflow and the [tag [x86] info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for those, not going to repeat it here.

BTW, this IMO stems from the unfortunate overcomplicated usage stack, do you have some particular reason why you follow such complex calling convention? How about some custom fastcall-like giving arguments and results in registers? It's also much more performant, but for me personally it's also easier to keep track of things and process stack correctly. I may add my own variant later to this answer, if I will try...

---

EDIT: full working example with register calling convention:

file: **`so_32b_pascal_triangle.asm`**

```
section .text

global _start
_start:
    mov     ecx,5       ; n
    mov     edx,2       ; k
    call    combi
    ; return to linux with sys_exit(result)
    mov     ebx,eax
    mov     eax,1
    int     80h

; ECX = n, EDX = k, returns result in EAX, no other register modified
; (_msfastcall-like convention, but extended to preserve ECX+EDX)
combi:   ; c(n, k) = c(n-1, k-1) + c(n-1, k),   c(i, 0) = c(i, i) = 1
    test    edx,edx     ; k == 0
    je      .basecases  ; c(i, 0) = 1
    cmp     edx,ecx     ; k == n
    je      .basecases  ; c(i, i) = 1
    ; 0 < k < n case:
    dec     ecx         ; n-1
    call    combi       ; EAX = c(n-1, k)
    push    esi
    mov     esi,eax     ; keep c(n-1, k) in ESI
    dec     edx         ; k-1
    call    combi       ; EAX = c(n-1, k-1)
    add     eax,esi     ; EAX = c(n-1, k-1) + c(n-1, k)
    ; restore all modified registers
    pop     esi
    inc     ecx
    inc     edx
    ret                 ; return result in EAX
.basecases:
    mov     eax,1
    ret
```

**compilation + run + result displayed:**

```
...$ nasm -f elf32 -F dwarf -g so_32b_pascal_triangle.asm -l so_32b_pascal_triangle.lst -w+all
...$ ld -m elf_i386 -o so_32b_pascal_triangle so_32b_pascal_triangle.o
...$ ./so_32b_pascal_triangle ; echo $?
10
...$
```

---

EDIT:

And for my own curiosity, tried to call it from C-ish C++ code (to verify the `fastcall` convention is working as expected even when interoperability with C/C++ is required):

The `so_32b_pascal_triangle.asm` file has same `combi:` code, but the beginning is modified (added global, removed `_start`):

```
section .text

global combi
; ECX = n, EDX = k, returns result in EAX, no other register modified
; (fastcall-like convention, but extended to preserve ECX+EDX)
combi:   ; c(n, k) = c(n-1, k-1) + c(n-1, k),   c(i, 0) = c(i, i) = 1
    ...
```

file `so_32b_pascal_triangle_Cpp.cpp`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

extern "C" __attribute__ ((fastcall)) uint32_t combi(uint32_t n, uint32_t k);

int main()
{
    for (uint32_t n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        printf("%*c", 1+2*(10-n), ' ');
        for (uint32_t k = 0; k <= n; ++k) {
            printf("%4d", combi(n, k));
            // 4-char width formatting - works for 3 digit results max.
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Build + test:

```
$ nasm -f elf32 -F dwarf -g so_32b_pascal_triangle.asm -l so_32b_pascal_triangle.lst -w+all
$ g++ -std=c++17 -c -m32 -O3 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra so_32b_pascal_triangle_Cpp.cpp
$ g++ -m32 so_32b_pascal_triangle*.o -o so_32b_pascal_triangle
$ ./so_32b_pascal_triangle
                        1
                      1   1
                    1   2   1
                  1   3   3   1
                1   4   6   4   1
              1   5  10  10   5   1
            1   6  15  20  15   6   1
          1   7  21  35  35  21   7   1
        1   8  28  56  70  56  28   8   1
      1   9  36  84 126 126  84  36   9   1
```